# Statistics Generation

Tags: java, eclipse

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


String WELCOME="Welcome to your postfix calculator\n====================\n";

        String input ="";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] inputArray;
        Double result = 0D;

        do{


        System.out.print(WELCOME);  
        System.out.println("'Please Enter 'f' to read from the file or 'k to enter the expressions manually, stop to Exit: :");     

        input  = scan.nextLine();

        switch(input)
        {
        case "f":
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////         



            try {

                Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter your file name: ");
                String path = lineScanner.nextLine();
                Scanner myfile = new Scanner(new File(path));
                 while (myfile.hasNext())
                 {
                     input = myfile.nextLine();
                     inputArray = input.split(" ");


                     if (inputArray.length == 3)
                      {
                    inputArray = input.split(" ");

                    try{   
                  Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
                  Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
                  String operator = inputArray[2];



                  switch (operator)
                  {
                    case "+":

                      result = number1 + number2;
                      break;

                    case "-":
                      result = number1 - number2;
                      break;

                    case "/":
                      result = number1 / number2;
                      break;

                    case "*":
                      result = number1 * number2;
                      break;

                    default:
                      System.out.println("Received unsupported operator: " + operator);
                      break;
                  }
                  System.out.println("Your expression is:" + number1 + operator + number2 );
                  System.out.println("Your answer is: " + result);


                  }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                  {
                      System.err.println("Invalid expression");
                      continue; 
                  }
                      }}}catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                            System.out.println("Your file is not found: -"+e.getMessage());

                        }


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                                   
            break;
        case "k":
                keyboardService();
                break;
        case "stop":
               break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid option");   
       }

    } while (!input.equals("stop"));

    System.out.print("Recieved stop command...");    


}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        private  static void keyboardService()
        {

            Double result = 0D;
            String  input  ="";
            int count =1;

            while (count ==1) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Welcome to your Postfix Calculator\n====================\n");
            System.out.println("Enter your postfix expression, OR to exit type stop:");
            input = scan.nextLine();


            if (input.toLowerCase().equals("stop"))
            {
              System.out.println("Received stop command...");
              System.exit(0);
            }//end of if statement

            else{
                try
                  {
              String[] inputArray = input.split(" ");

                  Double number1 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[0]);
                  Double number2 = Double.parseDouble(inputArray[1]);
                  String operator = inputArray[2];



                  if (inputArray.length == 3)
                  {

                  switch (operator)
                  {
                    case "+":

                      result = number1 + number2;
                      break;

                    case "-":
                      result = number1 - number2;
                      break;

                    case "/":
                      result = number1 / number2;
                      break;

                    case "*":
                      result = number1 * number2;
                      break;

                    default:
                      System.out.println("Received unsupported operator: " + operator);
                      break;
                  }
                  System.out.println("Your expression is:" + number1 + operator + number2 );
                  System.out.println("Your answer is: " + result);

                }else{
                    System.err.println("Invalid expression");
                }

              }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                  System.err.println("Invalid expression");
                  continue;
                }
              }


            }
          }

        }
```

Hello so i need to make this post-fix calculator more advanced. For the third requirement the program should be enhanced so that it generates some useful statistics about the expressions which have been evaluated. Specifically six different statistics should be gathered and displayed once evaluation is complete.

•   The highest overall result value.
•   The lowest overall result value.
•   The aggregate of all result values, i.e. all results added together.
•   The average result value.
•   The total number of invalid expressions.
•   The total number of valid expressions processed.

Just prior to program termination, the statistics should be displayed as follows –

### Evaluations complete

Highest result: 1024.5
Lowest result: -120
Aggregate result: 2212
Average result: 340
Invalid expressions: 6
Valid expressions: 150

Note: If the number of valid expressions is zero, then the highest, lowest and average should be shown as n/a.

I just don't know where to start. i was thinking of making another private static void for this part or continue in the keyboard. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a List object to your keyboardService method which will hold the results:

```
List<Double> results = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Add counters to your keyboardService method to count valid/invalid expressions;

```
int validExpressions=0;
int inValidExpressions=0;
```

Do adding to these objects as needed in your code.
Add the following after the stop call:

```
elseif (input.toLowerCase().equals("eval"))
        {
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          sb.append("Highest result:").append(getHighest(results));
          sb.append("Lowest result:").append(getLowest(results));
          //and so on ...
          System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
```

Add methods `getHighest(List<Double> results), getLowest(List<Double> results)`, etc.

Hope this helps you further...

Comment: Thank you I will definitely try that and let you know